# Spaces cant be used in string? c++

Tags: c++, string, cin

Basically I'm experimenting with polymorphism. I have 2 objects, a customer and an employee. a customer has a name and a complaint. An employee has a name and a salary.

In a loop, I take in these parameters and create a new Person to add to an array.

But here's my issue: If I put any spaces in the string, the loop races to the end.

```
Person *persons[10];

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof persons;i++)
{
    cout<<"Please type 1 for customer or 2 for Employee"<<endl;
    int q;
    cin>>q;
    string name;
    int salary;
    string complaint;


    if (q == 1)
    {
        cout<<"What is your name?"<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"What is your complaint"<<endl;
        cin>>complaint;

        personPtr = new Customer(name,complaint);
        cout<<"Created customer"<<endl<<endl;
        persons[i] = personPtr;
        cout<< "added to array"<<endl<<endl;
    }
    else if(q==2)
    {
        cout<<"What is your name?"<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"What is your salary"<<endl;
        cin>>salary;
        personPtr = new Employee(name,salary);
        persons[i] = personPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Sorry but i could not understand your input. Please try again"<<endl;
        i--;
        cin>>q;
    }
}
delete personPtr;
system("PAUSE");
```

Is there any special way to include strings?

Here's the customer and employee classes for reference.

```
class Person
{
public:
Person(const string n)
{name = n;}; // initialise the name
virtual void printName();
protected:
string name;
};


class Customer:public Person
{
public:
string complaint;

Customer(string name, string cm)
    :Person(name)
{       
    complaint=cm;
}
virtual void printName();
};

class Employee:public Person
{
public:
int salary;

Employee(string name,int sl)
    :Person(name)
{       
    salary = sl;
}
virtual void printName();
};
```

Comment: have you tried putting quotes around the input string, it sounds like your spaces are being interpreted as separate arguments

Comment: @Joe: That's nonsense if the strings are read from the console using `operator>>`. That operator doesn't implement handling of quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The input operator

   ```
   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::string&)
   ```

   only ever ***reads input up to the next whitespace character***. (That's just the way it was specified when Jerry Schwartz invented IO streams 25 years ago.) If you need to read whole *lines*, then

   ```
   std::istream& getline(std::istream&, std::string&, char='\n')
   ```

   is what you need to use:

   ```
   std::string name;
   std::getline(std::cin, name);
   ```
2. ***Input might fail***. For example, reading an `int` might fail because there are only non-numeric digits in the input buffer. If stream operations fail, there are state bits that will get set in the stream. After a failure, a stream will not perform any further operations. Operands of `>>` will then be left untouched.
   So you need to ***check whether your input operations succeeded*** before using the data. The simplest way to do this is to check the stream after input operations:

   ```
   if(!std::cin) {
     // input failed
   }
   ```

Comment: so i need to overload the >> operator. Thats even more advanced than what im doing now. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @OVERTONE: After a quite some time on SO I am used to people glossing over the details of a _question_ before they answer, but questioners glossing over an answer is news to me. _What on earth have I written that makes you think you need to overload `operator>>`??_

Comment: @OVERTONE: no, you don't need to. you misunderstood the answer.

Comment: @overtone, he means use `getline`

Comment: In short, write `getline(cin, name)`.

Comment: wow. It sounds like ive really offended you and i apologize for that. I didnt just gloss over your question, i wouldn't have asked if i wasnt interested in the answer. I was simply having a hard time understanding what was going on in the code. I genuinely believed you were overloading the >> operator by swapping >> for getLine. Im not the most educated in c++ ok? were on totally different levels here so i'm sorry if I misunderstood your answer. Im still trying to understand how to use it.

Comment: In short, instead of using 'cin >>', which reads to the next whitespace character. 
You should use 'getline(cin, name)', which reads the next line from the std::cin stream; which appears to be what you have asked for.
Simple error checking has also been provided by sbi for you.

Comment: @OVERTONE: I wasn't really offended, just very puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>First i think `sizeof` needs parenthesis around the object.</strike> (See comment below)

Second cin ignores whitespaces when making an input. So "Jose   " becomes "Jose". That might be the problem you're having.

Comment: sizeof needs parentheses ONLY when used with types. E.g. sizeof (int). With expressions the syntax is sizeof expr. Since if expr is an expression (expr) is too an expression, sizeof (expr) is equivalent to sizeof expr.

Comment: Is there a replacement for sizeof in arrays? I was actually told to use it on stack. Never really knew what i was getting into.

Comment: @Overtone Since this is c++ there is always vector.size() ;-) I don't really understand what you mean by using it on stack.

Comment: using it on "stack overflow". I missed a word, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

@sbi already answered your main question.  But there are a couple other things you may want to pay attention to.

1. You are holding onto pointers after they are deleted, which can cause problems later.
2. You should use `_getch()` or `cin.get()` instead of `system("PAUSE")`.  Using system calls to keep your command window open is not ideal.

Comment: really? so how do i fully delete pointers, or rather the data they're carrying.

Comment: system("PAUSE") is just the way i was shwn i guess. just like i used to use /n instead of endl. but thanks for the advice

Comment: Actually, you have a memory leak (you allocate 10 objects, but only the last one will get deleted).  The best way to avoid this is to use something like `shared_ptr` or `scoped_ptr` instead of managing the memory yourself.