# Replacing spaces in a string by %20 in C++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void removeSpaces(std::string );

int main()
{
        std::string inputString;
        std::cout<<"Enter the string:"<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>inputString;

        removeSpaces(inputString);

        return 0;
}



void removeSpaces(std::string str)
{
        size_t position = 0;
        for ( position = str.find(" "); position != std::string::npos; position = str.find(" ",position) )
        {
                str.replace(position ,1, "%20");
        }

        std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
}
```

I am not able to see any output. For example

```
Enter Input String: a b c
Output = a
```

What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [spaces cant be used in string? c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992229/spaces-cant-be-used-in-string-c)

Answer (score 9):

```
std::cin>>inputString;
```

stops at the first space.  Use:

```
std::getline(std::cin, inputString);
```

instead.

Comment: And a little diagnostic output before calling `removeSpaces()` would have solved this before the question would even have become necessary...

Answer (score 5):

`cin` by default stops at whitespace.

Change your input to:

```
// will not work, stops on whitespace
//std::cin>>inputString;

// will work now, will read until \n
std::getline(std::cin, inputString);
```

Answer (score 0):

another better way to do is to count no of spaces, create new string of length = old length +2*count and start moving characters from old string to new string except for a space replace it with %20....

**Implementation**
http://justprogrammng.blogspot.com/2012/06/replace-all-spaces-in-string-by-20.html